# Case Statement for TableName

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure which updates table column based on sent condition. The queries which i wrote dont work.

First is if I try to set Table name as variable.

```
Create Procedure Proc_Test
@Tblname varchar(20)
AS BEGIN

Update @Tblname
Set IsValid = 1;

End
```

this fails.

Second I have tried is case statement

Create Procedure Proc_Test
    @Tblname varchar(20)
    AS BEGIN

```
Case @Tblname 
WHEN 1 THEN Update tbl1 set ISValid = 1;

WHEN 2 THEN Update tbl2 set ISValid = 1;

End
```

END

This also throws exception.

Any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use dynamic sql if you want the table name to be variable, otherwise you need to use conditional statements to filter based on table names, which would be ok if there weren't too many table names to work through.

### Conditional Approach

```
declare @Tblname varchar(20) = 'Table1'

if @Tblname = 'Table1'
begin
    update Table1
    set IsValid = 1
    -- where some condition is met?
end

if @Tblname = 'Table2'
begin
    update Table2
    set IsValid = 1
    -- where some condition is met?
end
```

### Dynamic Sql Approach

```
declare @SQLString nvarchar(100);
declare @Tblname varchar(20) = 'Table1'

set @SQLString = N'update ' + @Tblname + ' set IsValid = 1';

execute sp_executesql @SQLString
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_Test
@Tblname VARCHAR(20)
AS 

BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL varchar(1000);
SET @SQL = 'Update '+@Tblname+' Set IsValid = 1;'
EXECUTE (@SQL);
END
```